# What's more common – use of indefinite articles or not use in CTAs?

Tags: phrases

When designing UIs, what is more commonly expected – to use indefinite articles or not to use them for CTAs (call to action; like a button)?

Example button 'Add an Account' vs 'Add Account'

and is there a rule for it?

Comment: People are used to the headlinese of Stop, Go Slow, Pay Bill, Add Account. Add **an** Account befuddles those looking to add 2: Where is that function?

Comment: In my view it is important to be consistent in using or not using the article, but not very important which way you decide to go.

Comment: This should be covered by a style guide for a platform or application. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/guidelines) has incredibly detailed guidelines for Windows UX. Failing that, copy existing applications.